# How can I access the certificate(.pfx) attached to https post request from postman, inside a controller in dotnet core web api 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, x509certificate

I am attaching a certificate to a post request from postman(setting-> add certificate section) and hitting a contoller present in dotnet core web api3. [postman adding certificate image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmajV.png)

Now I want to access the certificate and its thumbprint from a controller that I am hitting.
How can I acces the certificate and thumbprint from inside the contoller?

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void getcertificate()
  {
    // I want to access the certificate(.pfx file) and its thumbprint here.
  }
```

How   Can I access the certificate and retrieve thumbprint inside this controller.

Comment: And what makes you think that it will be available inside controller ? What do want to.do with certificate inside controller.

Comment: I want to access the thumbprint and query the database using the thumbprint. Is it even possible to acces the certificate inside the contorller? What other options do I have to acces the certificate thumbprnt?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Using this I can acces the thumbprint from controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the thumbprint inside controller like this

```
HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate.Thumbprint
```

Hope it helps.